# What are all the parameters for iso-scan?

Tags: live-cd, pxe

I am trying to use a "boot from iso" method on a Windows computer. The iso file is on a small ext4 partition on `/dev/sda3`. `/dev/sda[12]` are NTFS.

The normal iso-scan/filename fails (`/dev/sda1` can't be mounted because of hibernation issues due to the freeze software we are using).

I suspect that iso-scan has other parameters than `/filename` (maybe /device or /path) with which I can direct the scan.

Does anyone know these extra parameters? They don't seem to be documented in any place that I can find.

Comment: The liveBoot "disk" includes other files which allow the operating system to run. If you ever made a boot disk it is similar. The OS needs specific files along with the image (`.iso`) in order to know how to run from the disk. I am not sure if this is the issue, but since you tagged [tag:pxe] I am assuming you wish to host an `.iso` and boot from it.

Comment: I have no problem booting the entire thing from PXE, including the iso, so I don't think that's the issue. I can also pretty easily load the same kernel and initrd via GRUB to boot an iso, but not on the machines with this problem. It's just that the system tries to scan /dev/sda1, can't and gives up before scanning other partitions.

Comment: Ok I understand now. I can point you to [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-666267.html) lots of reading, but it seems as if it is possible (although they did this on version 7.XX? I am guessing with a floppy). This is the closest I have found though

Comment: This is an interesting "workaround" in that it puts the iso *as* /dev/sda3 instead of putting the image on a partition file system there. I will have to try it to see if there is a difference. Thanks.
If this works, I will answer my own question later.

Answer (score 0):

`iso-scan` is wired to not ask anything by default, so it will mount all known drives one by one and look for the iso in them.

But if you run it with very low debconf priority it will ask whether it should look into all devices or let you select which ones (`shared/ask_device=manual`) and in the latter case, which ones (`shared/enter_device=/dev/<SOMEDEV>`)

Both values can be preseeded from the kernel command line.